# How to use Numeric Up/Down Control Text Input?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

[image]

I want this kind of functionality in my PowerApps. Kindly tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Power Apps default control similar to your requirements.

But, you can develop such control easy using variables & buttons.

Refer below links for more information & detailed steps:

1. [Understand variables in canvas apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables)
2. [+ and - Button to add and subtract from a Quantity](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/and-Button-to-add-and-subtract-from-a-Quantity/td-p/21169)

Also, check this video which is similar to your requirements: [Power Apps | Persisted Button Pressed Numeric Up/Dn Control](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCdYXMBEhuo)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article to guide you to create the Numeric Up/Down control in Power Apps

- [#PowerApps: Numeric Up/Down control with persisted button press event using components](http://dynamicsgpblogster.blogspot.com/2019/03/powerapps-numeric-updown-control-with.html)